# How can you remove the interrupter (top bar) levers from the Giant Avail 5?

Tags: road-bike, brakes, interrupter-brakes

I'm looking to gain a little extra space on my handlebars and I do not use these brakes, so I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to remove them.

The spec is:

> Brake Levers  Shimano 2300 w/ Tektro RL720 Top Bar Levers

[image]

Comment: Could you be a bit more extensive in your description, maybe also with some pictures for us to see, how your handle bar looks like now and what you want to have removed?

Comment: I think the answers below are a bit of a faff (but correct), so I suggest an alternative: leave the interrupter levers on and use a [bar extender](http://www.topeak.com/products/xtras/barxtender).

Comment: Why do you want to remove them? If it is just to mount lights, bells, phone or whatever, then a bar extender is a much better idea IMO. There are quite a few different styles of those, depending on exactly what you're after.

Answer (score 3):

To remove the crosstop levers from the bar tops you will have to:

Remove the inner brake cables

Remove the bar tape

Remove the brake cable housing between the main brake levers and the crosstop levers and the crosstop levers and the front brake / frame boss.

Remmove the crosstop levers from the bar (they should be held on by a simple clamp with 1 allen bolt).

Install new lengths of cable housing between the main brake levers and the front brake / frame boss.

Re-install the inner brake cables and re-wrap the bars

Comment: Better leave them on. They are most practical if you've gotten the hang of it!

Answer (score 1):

A simpler alternative would be to use inline barrel adjusters to join the two sections of outer. That would avoid having to re-wrap the bars and means you could put the levers back in if you wanted to. Just release the inner wire from the brake, pull it out as far as the interrupter lever, remove the lever, inster the barrel adjuster and re-thread. Then wind the adjuster out until the cable outers sit properly on handlebars.

It may even be cheaper (new tape vs adjusters). The disadvantage is that the adjusters will be lumps right where you're gripping the bars sometimes, extra wear on the cables and having to deal with them every time you replace the brake cable or outer.

The adjusters cost about $20 look like this:

[image]

Note that most of the ones you find online will be for gear cables only, they're not strong enough for brake cables. If they break, your brakes stop working. So be careful to buy the right ones.

Comment: I think this is a good idea, since its somewhat conveniently placed. I wouldn't run it under the tape though - if it had interrupter bars, this would likely mean re-running the tape anyway (and I'd rather just cut a new brake housing then)